# SharePoint 2013 - Get Custom Field Value via REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have SPList which contains Custom Type Column (inherited from Lookup). When I try to retrieve its items via REST API I'm getting an error:

```
/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists/getbyid(guid'list-id')/Items(item-id)

The value for field 'column name' of type 'custom field type' cannot be serialized.
```

Does REST API not support Custom Types? Thank you.

Comment: @tarzanbappa I'm guessing you don't work with SharePoint. This is quite a binary question and your comment is very unproductive given that all someone needs to answer is already here.

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer, but I've been unable to retrieve custom typed values using REST in the past

Comment: @jasonscript During my search I've seen several people saying the same, but didn't find any official limitations list for the REST API unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to retrieve a lookup field's value with **expand** keyword

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Customers')/items?$select=Title,Affiliation/Id,Affiliation/Title&$expand=Affiliation
```

you can find a detailed explanation on this blog
https://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/simplifying-sharepoint-2013-rest-api

Note the the URL is different because you have to use SharePoint 2013 rest API.
The url you provided is the SharePoint 2010's way to use Rest API. It is still here in 2013 though.

Comment: True, but $expand does not work with **Custom Type** inherited from lookup.

Answer (score -2):

@Oleg Bul.. Go through this article and become pro.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx :D

Few important parts from the post regarding your query.

**$expand** - Specifies which projected fields from a joined list are returned.

When a SharePoint list has a lookup field to another list, this effectively serves as a join of the two lists. You can use the $expand option to return projected fields from the joined list. For example, if the Books list has a PublishedBy field that looks up to the Name field of a Publisher list, you can return those names with this URL:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle(
  'Books')/items?$select=Title,PublishedBy/Name&$expand=PublishedBy
```

---

**Updated ans :-**

Possible solutions i can think of..

1. try with $select='*' to fetch all the columns
2. Extend and deploy your own REST endpoint [Article on creating REST endpoint](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Extending-SharePoint-2013-c39d01ae)
3. Create calculated column and try copying the value of lookup custom column as it is and fetch the calculated column in your query.

Comment: True, but $expand does not work with **Custom Type** inherited from lookup.

Comment: did you try fetching custom column type from parent list first ?

Comment: My custom lookup is configured to display simple single text column from another list and yes, I can successfully fetch items from that parent list using the same query.

Comment: Solutions i can think of right nowtry with $select='*' to fetch all the columns

Comment: 1. Same error; 2. Yes, but I am interested in OOTB services; 3. As far as I remember, calculated columns does not work with any lookups.

Comment: @OlegBul can u please try one thing, create sharepoint designer workflow  and on new item addition trigger copy the value of custom lookup column in extra column.

Comment: I know it's old.. but did you find any solution ? i'm facing the same problem